# Xubuntu and mouse scrolling direction

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, scrolling

I'm using xubuntu (not unity) and mouse scrolling works totally wrong. I see first comments on this dated 2011. Now it is 2017 and everything is the same mess.

So. I'm using xubuntu. And I like natural mouse scrolling direction - the same way it works in MacOS X. If you want to move your page up you scroll two fingers up. If scroll down then down.

I have touchpad. By default I have reverse scrolling direction. Scrolling fingers up scroll page down, left to right. If I turn on reverse scrolling  for the touchpad then I get natural scrolling direction for up/down. But left right direction is still unnatural. And separate issue is google chrome (not chromium, I didn't check it). My Chrome version is 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit). And it totally ignores system settings. It has always unnatural scrolling direction for up/down.

Comment: It's the same in 18.04. I'm solving it by removing Xubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the scrolling direction by running this in a console.

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=-58; synclient HorizScrollDelta=-58
```

If you want keep the reverse scroll direction after restarting do the following:

Create a script `/usr/local/share/set_natural_scroll.sh` with the following contents.  This is the script that we will run on startup.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Sets the scrolling direction to 'natural'
synclient VertScrollDelta=-58
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-58
```

Create a file `~/.config/autostart/scroll_startup.desktop` with the following contents.  This will configure the script to be run on startup.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Script
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/local/share/set_natural_scroll.sh
Icon=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Hidden=false
GenericName=
GenericName[en_US]=
```

When xfce starts it will now run your script and setup the scroll direction.

References: [Wellllby](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crouton/comments/8imb36/google_chrome_opposite_scroll_direction_in_xfce/) and [Brinson](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=5550).

Comment: Thank you copy pasting thing from thread that is mentioned in header. That doesn't work. Synclient is for touchpad, not for a mouse. So that doesn't work for mouse.